# “Two times as fast”

Tags: word-problem

Simple word problem, but I am confused:

"It takes me $12$ hours to read a book at normal pace; if I read it **$\mathbf2$ times as fast**, how many hours does it take?"

The given answer is $4$ hours, but I thought it would be $6$ hours since $$ \frac{12\text{ hrs}}2 = 6\text{ hrs}\,?$$

Comment: Your notation is not clear.  You use "2x"' to mean, apparently, "two times", but also use "x" as a variable.

Comment: @user247327 changed

Comment: You are interpreting correctly the expression "twice as fast" (and/or "two times as fast").

Comment: After the edit, I agree with you.  Twice as fast means you read it in half the time.

Comment: You could ask another question: If I walk normally, it takes me 10 seconds to walk 10 meters. Therefore, if I walk **two times as fast**, it takes me only 5 seconds to walk 10 meters. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Had the question instead been "It takes me 12 hours to read a book at normal pace; if I read it **2 times *faster***, how many hours does it take?", then I would interpret the hypothetical speed to be **3 times as fast** as the normal pace, in which case the corresponding duration is $$\frac{12\text{ hrs}}3=4\text{ hrs}.$$